# Problem to find field equations with Euler-Lagrange in field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

I have the Euler-Lagrange equations, as stated in field-theory:

$$\partial_\nu \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\nu \phi_\rho)}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_\rho}=0$$

However I'm having some simple problems to find the motion equation for those Lagrangian densities:

$$L= -\left( \partial_\mu A^\nu \right)\left( \partial_\nu A^\mu \right) + \frac{1}{2}A_\mu A^\mu + \frac{\lambda}{2} \left( \partial_\mu A^\mu \right)^2$$

and

$$L = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}m^2A_\mu A^\mu$$
with
$$F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\mu A_\nu.$$

Do I have to lower every index beforehand, to match the lower index in $\phi$ in E-L equation? Could anyone solve them step-by-step to learn what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Tips:

1) Remember that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are dummy indices. It will be easier to see if you lower all indexes, but with pratice this won't be necessary anymore.

2) For terms like $(\partial_ \mu A^\mu)^2$, write them as $g^{\mu \nu} g^{\sigma \rho} (\partial_\mu A_\nu)  (\partial_\sigma A_\rho$) and use Leibniz's rule .

3) For terms like $A^\mu A_\mu$ just do the same thing.

4) Remember that $\frac{\partial A^\mu}{\partial A^\nu} = \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}$ and $\frac{\partial \partial_\sigma A_\mu}{\partial \partial_\rho A_\nu} = \delta^{\rho}_{\sigma} \delta^{\nu}_{\mu}$.

Comment: You have no idea how you've helped me already. Could you please check if my answer is correct for the first density? $-2 \Box A^\alpha +2\lambda g^{\alpha \sigma}A^\delta \partial_\nu A_\delta - m^2 A^\rho$ Something feels terribly wrong with the indexes and the factor two in front term...

Comment: Probably off-topic, but could be handy. Wolfram Mathematica can variate lagrangians. Take a look at **VariationalD**. You could use it to check your result.

Comment: Ok, never used this tool before. However does it recognize the distinction in upper and downer indexes? I'm looking into it and sees that it does not...

Comment: Edison, I didn't do the calculation, but I can say that your answer is wrong because of index placement. 

The Euler-Lagrange equations you want only have one free index. Your answer has (assuming you confused $\rho$ and $\alpha$ in the last term) $\alpha$, $\sigma$ and $\nu$ as free indexes. Take extra care with the $\delta$'s that will appear in the derivatives.